# ¿Cómo obtener el id de un listado y el valor de un component <select> en Angular?

Tags: java, sql, angular, spring-boot, html-select

Tengo la siguiente tabla y en el campo **ESTADO** se muestra una lista despegable con todos los estatus que hay, y solo ese campo se puede modificar, tengo en el select el value 0 para que por Default tenga seleccionado el estatus actual que esta en la tabla **CONTROL**,

tengo los siguientes métodos en el component. ts que son los que ocupo para llenar la tabla

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
            <th scope="col">COMENTARIO</th>
            <th scope="col">HORA INICIO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contr of control">
            <td>{{contr.id}}</td>
            <td>
                <select class="select" (change)="onChangeList($event, contr)">
                    <option value="0">{{contr.cveEstado}}</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado">
                        {{estatus.descripcionEstado}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>{{contr.comentario}</td>
            <td>{{contr.horaInicio}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

y en el component.ts

```
    control: Control[] = [];
    controlModel: Control =  new Control();
    estadoModel: Estatus[] = [];
    idEst: number;

constructor(private controlService: ControlService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerListaControl();
    this.obtenerListaEstado();
}
    


    private obtenerListaControl(){
    this.controlService.obtenerControl().subscribe(response => {
      this.control = response.data;
    });
   }

   private obtenerListaEstado(){
    this.controlService.obtenerEstatus().subscribe(resp => {
      this.estadoModel = resp.data;
    });
   }
   
   onChangeList(e,contr){
    this.idEst = e.target.value;
    console.log("Prueba filaseleccionada:::::" +e.target.value.contr);
  }

   guardar(){
    this.controlModel.cveEstado= this.idEst;
    this.controlService.updateEstado(this.controlModel).subscribe(data=>{
      this.controlModel=data;
    })
   }
```

El método **obtenerListaControl()** es para listar lo que hay en la tabla **CONTROL**, el método **obtenerListaEstado()** es para listar la descripcion de los estados de la tabla **ESTADO**, ya que en la tabla **CONTROL** solo trae la clave del estado y no la descripcion, el método **guardar()** que es para que realice la actualizacion en la BD y manda a llamar al servicio con el método **updateEstatus()**.

Lo que hace ahorita es recuperar el valor de la opcion que se seleccione a traves del metodo **(change)="onChangeList($event)"** y se lo seteo al campo **this.controlModel.cveEstado= this.idEst;** para obtener la nueva clave del estado , pero lo que no sé , es como recupero el **id** de la fila en la cual voy a actualizar el estado, para que mi metodo en el service se ejecute de manera correcta ya que como parametro recibe un Objeto del tipo Control,
si modifico el estatus de la primera fila o de la ultima, como obtengo ese **id**, para que la actualizacion se haga en ese registro, alguien podria ayudarme en eso por favor,

service.ts

```
updateEstatus(control: Control){
    return this.httpClient.put<Control>(this.baseUrl+"/"+control.id,control);
  }
```

Este es el metodo en el backend

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ControlEntity actualizar(@RequestBody ControlEntity control,
            @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        control.setId(id);
        return controlService.actualizar(control);
    }
```

Comment: Manda la fila o solo el ID de la fila seleccionada en la función que usas para obtener el valor que cambio: `onChangeList(e, filaSeleccionada)`

Comment: @René pero filaSeleccionada, donde la declaro en la tabla? y en el componente, como lo obtengo?

Comment: `*ngFor="let contr of control"`, ahí esta tu nombre de fila. `onChangeList(e, contr)`

Comment: @René pero en mi componente como recupero el valor?  seria asi? no entiendo bien , asi lo hice y me manda   undefined                                                                                                            onChangeList(e: any){
    this.idEst = e.target.value;
    console.log(" PRUEBA FILA SELECCIONADA:::::" + e.target.value.contr);
  }

Comment: @René actualice  el cambio que agregue en la tabla y en el componente

Comment: No es un punto, es una coma `onChangeList( e , contr )`

Comment: @René, ya lo actualice en la pregunta, pero al momento de correrlo y ver el console, manda undefined, como veo los datos en el componente?

Comment: En tu onChangeList( e , contr ), ahí ya tienes el valor en el contr, por qué no usas el contr ?

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes `e.target.value.contr`? Por eso te da undefined. `contr` no está ligado al evento. Vas a usar contr.id para mandar el valor a tu base de datos.

Comment: gracias @René, ya lo cambie y ya funciona